# View unanswered questions with most recent first

Tags: support, search, unanswered-questions, sorting

At https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered the answers appear to be listed in order of number of votes. Which means it basically never changes (most voted first).

Is there a way to see unanswered questions listed with most recent first?

Comment: Would https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest be a workaround? There are some differences in which questions the two unanswered list show, but I currently can remember which.

Comment: @samcarter yes that seems to do it, how did you find this link?

Comment: @samcarter oh I see, basically clicking on top left for pop-menu where I go always for Questions and then choose Unanswered. Well I am really almost as lazy as the "do the TikZ for me" guys. Would you care turning this into an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I found it a bit long-winded to use this pop-menu to go to questions, instead I use a user-script that changed the link of the `{TeX}` logo to go to questions.

Comment: I actually also like [this search](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions) which is rather good at looking for questions that fit your profile. (The only downside is that it also lists your own unanswered questions, if there are any.)

Comment: @marmot Thanks, I wonder how you came to know about this!

Comment: Someone (I forgot who, for me the names of humans sound all the same;-) posted it on the chat. [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/queries) is the complete list.

Comment: @marmot as if this site was not already efficient enough into black-holing one's time! I will sure stay safely far from that list of queries...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a special "unanswered" list which can be sorted by date: https://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest

For everybody who is like me hiding the left hand sidebar, this can be hard to find as it hides behind the three horizontal lines at the top left of the headline:

[image]

If I remember correctly there are some differences and the two list don't show the same questions, but I forgot which differences this are.

Comment: It also includes questions having received answers with no upvotes.

Comment: @jfbu Answers without upvote are also included at the very end of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered

Comment: indeed... but your alternative link achieving sorted by date presentation makes them more visible.

Comment: @jfbu That's true!